# Posting current location to rails from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking, core-location

I am building a rails-backed iphone app that uses AFNetworking to create posts at specific locations. So the post model has lat/lng parameters that should be filled in with the client's current location.
At this point, the posts can be made, but the lat/lng comes up as null.
In my (save:) method I pass a conditional to see if a location was found- this is what is failing i.e. "No Location" is logged.

```
- (void)save:(id)sender {
    [self getLocation];
    NSArray *locations;
    CLLocation *location = [locations objectAtIndex:0];

    Post *post = [[Post alloc] init];
    post.content = self.contentTextView.text;
    post.photoData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image);

    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    ProgressView *progressView = [ProgressView presentInWindow:self.view.window];
    if (location) {
        [post savePostAtLocation:location withBlock:^(CGFloat progress) {
            [progressView setProgress:progress];
        } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            [progressView dismiss];
            if (success) {
                [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No Location");
    }
}
```

I have also attempted to implement a locationManager like so

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    [self getLocation];
}

-(CLLocation *) getLocation{
    CLLocationManager * locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 80.0f;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation * location = [locationManager location];
    return location;
}
```

I think ideally I would implement the savePostAtlocation in the CLLocationManagerDelegate where I could pass in the locations array like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations objectAtIndex:0 /* firstObject */];
    if (location) {
        [Post createPostAtLocation:location...
```

But I want to have the post created onSave so I am trying to identify the location but running into some problems..
How do I properly get the current location and pass it into the dictionary?
Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think you have a slight misunderstanding about how CLLocationManager is designed to work. It looks like you are trying to call `[self getLocation]` from inside `locationManager:didUpdateLocations`. This is not correct. Try something like this, inside your `save` method that is called when you press your button (I would remove the code that's currently in there while testing):

```
CLLocationManager * locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 80.0f;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then it will start generating location data. When that happens, the phone will automatically call `locationManager:didUpdateLocations` very rapidly. Then, in `locationManager:didUpdateLocations` you could use:

```
CLLocation * location = [manager location];
NSLog(@"%@", location);
```

To see your location data in the console.

What I have written here should get the phone generating location data for you. What you say about `createPostAtLocation:` in `locationManager:didUpdateLocations` is probably the correct way to go. When you get the location data, call [manager stopUpdatingLocation] to make the phone stop, then post the location data you got back to your server.